# How do I set up a subdomain on my locally hosted IIS server?

Tags: iis, mediawiki

I have IIS (8.5) running on a local Windows Server 2012 computer named (for the purposes of this question) `SERVER_1`. This server has CGI/FastCGI running and working on it. I use this server for various things, but one of the things I use it for is for hosting an internal Wiki (MediaWiki). My design choice, not looking for online solutions.

Everything is working with my current binding that is:

```
Type    Host Name    Port    IP Address     Binding Information
http    SERVER_1     80      *
```

If I go to a Windows browser from an intranet computer I can hit my Wiki page by going to `http://SERVER_1` (unless it's on Mac - different issue I haven't figured out yet).

What I'm looking to do, however, is have it be accessible by going to `http://wiki.SERVER_1` but no matter how I configure the bindings it doesn't seem to work. For example:

```
Type    Host Name         Port    IP Address     Binding Information
http    wiki.SERVER_1     80      *
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think Server Fault would be a better place for this question. And also, it's not really about MediaWiki, and is about DNS, so you might want to swap some tags.

Comment: add an entry to your hosts file for wiki.SERVER_1